# How to get street name from osm.pbf file in OpenStreetMap

Tags: python, pandas, openstreetmap

You can download any dataset from here https://download.geofabrik.de/australia-oceania.html

Here's my code

```
import osmium as osm
import pandas as pd

class OSMHandler(osm.SimpleHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        osm.SimpleHandler.__init__(self)
        self.osm_data = []

    def tag_inventory(self, elem, elem_type):
        for tag in elem.tags:
            self.osm_data.append([elem_type, 
                                   elem.id, 
                                   elem.version,
                                   elem.visible,
                                   pd.Timestamp(elem.timestamp),
                                   elem.uid,
                                   elem.user,
                                   elem.changeset,
                                   len(elem.tags),
                                   tag.k, 
                                   tag.v])

    def node(self, n):
        self.tag_inventory(n, "node")

    def way(self, w):
        self.tag_inventory(w, "way")

    def relation(self, r):
        self.tag_inventory(r, "relation")

osmhandler = OSMHandler()
# scan the input file and fills the handler list accordingly
osmhandler.apply_file("/DATA/user/nabih/pitcairn-islands-latest.osm.pbf")

# transform the list into a pandas DataFrame
data_colnames = ['type', 'id', 'version', 'visible', 'ts', 'uid',
                 'user', 'chgset', 'ntags', 'tagkey', 'tagvalue']
df_osm = pd.DataFrame(osmhandler.osm_data, columns=data_colnames)
```

Here's the `df_osm`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Street names are values of the `name` key of `highway` elements (see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features#Highway for all possible highway types, you may want to further filter it in the query). You can then self join all `highway` rows with their `name` rows on `id`:

```
df_osm.loc[df_osm.tagkey=='highway', ['id', 'tagvalue']].merge(
    df_osm.loc[df_osm.tagkey=='name', ['id', 'tagvalue']],
    on='id', suffixes=['_kind', '_name'])
```

Result for `pitcairn-islands-latest.osm.pbf`:

```
           id tagvalue_kind            tagvalue_name
0  1034153953   residential                Main Road
1  1034161481   residential  Hill of Difficulty Road
```

---

If you want to also include national names you can replace `df_osm.tagkey=='name'` with `df_osm.tagkey.str.startswith('name')`. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:name for details and other possible names.